# Using gpio-pca953x i2c expander Linux driver from userspace without device tree

Tags: x86, linux-device-driver, i2c, gpio, acpi

I have an x86 computer with a TCA6408A i2c expander, specifically a PCSF51 board. I can use i2c with the expander to set the GPIO pins on the computer to high or low. I saw that there is a Linux driver (gpio-pca953x.c) which can expose a GPIO device for this expander (so as to not have to interface with i2c directly). How can I instantiate this driver such that a GPIO device is visible in /dev?

I found this [documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.28/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt), and other similar questions on stack overflow, but my computer is x86 so it does not have a device tree. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106568/how-to-programmatically-use-gpio-expander-driver-in-linux) asks for a similar thing, but the user uses device tree. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628807/how-to-interact-with-the-linux-pca953x-c-driver-how-does-one-utilize-this-drive) also asks the same, but there is no mention of how to load and set up the driver, and my board does not have the Raspberry Pi's /boot/config.txt.

Comment: Maybe you browsed answers with different tags? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817205/2511795. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095840/adding-i2c-client-devices-on-x86-64/.